# Windows Forms Control.Invoke(Action) blocked while MessageBox is shown?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

I have to debug code by a former colleague.
The application is part of a machine control. The machine is already delivered to our customer, which restricts my debugging abilities.

The situation is as follows:
A Windows Forms MessageBox is shown:

```
if (MessageBox.Show(toask, "Überprüfung", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, 
                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly)
                    != DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Do something here
    return;
}
```

The user does not click the box away for at least half a minute, because he has to do something, when the box is shown.
Meanwhile, I need the callback method of a System.Timers.Timer (500 ms, AutoReset == false) event to be executed:

```cs
private void timerLoop_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Action updateUI = () =>
    {
        // Do some extensive work, accessing Windows Forms controls.
        // I'm expecting a bool variable to be set here.
    }
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(updateUI);
    else
        updateUI();

    timerLoop.Start();
}
```

The bool variable mentioned in the code block is not set, although it should be.
Since the callback method is always executed in a thread other than the UI thread, `this.Invoke(updateUI)` is called (probably could get rid of `if(this.InvokeRequired)`).

My question is: is the invoked `updateUI` blocked from executing, while the MessageBox is shown? This would explain the applications behavior.
And if so, what can I do to force the callback's execution while MessageBox is shown?
Would `BeginInvoke()` help?

**ADDENDUM 1:** The timer was formerly a Windows.Forms.Timer instead of a Systems.Timers.Timer. I changed it trying to solve another issue. Before that, the application worked in the situation described above (apart from other issues).

Seems, this info is relevant for the question? However, I don't understand why the Forms.Timer's callback is handled during MessageBox, but not the Control.Invokes in the Timers.Timers callback?

Comment: There is only on UI thread ... And if it's blocked non of the UI messages would be executed ... If you use  `BeginInvoke`  then `timerLoop_Elapsed` will not be blocked but you will spam UI thread with `updateUI` call and this will run immediately when UI thread would free **(think about "UI thread" as message queue consumer, `BeginInvoke` just puts something on queue, UI thread have to pick it and execute ... then pick another message and so on)**

Comment: If that is a common pattern in that software you might want to think about replacing the MessageBox with something that gives feedback without blocking the main thread (for example a non-modal dialog and if needed block user accessing the other forms by other means)

Comment: There's a simple workaround that you can implement without changing the logic of your code: add an *overlay*, a semi-transparent Form that overlaps the Form that is now showing the MessageBox. Use a non-modal Dialog, that has its Owner set to the overlay, to show the message. You cannot click anything in the Form that is under the overlay (but you can see it). The UI updates work as usual -- If you don't need a modal Dialog (the MessageBox), then just replace it with a non-modal custom version

Comment: Message boxes run their own modal message loop, separate from `Application.Run`. It's possible (but I think unlikely) that it's not dispatching `Invoke` messages properly

Comment: "The bool variable mentioned in the code block is not set" how do you know, how are you checking that?

Comment: I do not "know" about the variable, but it would be the best explanation for the application's behavior after the MessageBox is clicked away. Like mentioned in my question, my debugging abilities are limited :(

Comment: I think the messagebox disables all other controls on the underlying form, so probably the update is not happening. How about you do `tBTimersTimer.Invoke((Action)(() => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)));`

Comment: It did not make a difference, apart from the time being output to the console.

Comment: My point being: the timer **is** working, it's just that the text control is not being updated because it's disabled by the messagebox. Maybe try forcing it with `tBFormsTimer.Refresh()`

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: I observed that both textboxes are updated even when the MessageBox is shown. Which answers my question. Unfortunately not the way I would have liked... I moved my experimental code to this question's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the idea to test my theory with a little test application:

```cs
namespace Timers_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            timersTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;


            winFormsTimer.Start();
            timersTimer.Start();
        }

        private System.Timers.Timer timersTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);


        private void winFormsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tBFormsTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        }

        private void OnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            tBTimersTimer.Invoke((Action)(() => tBTimersTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")));
        }

        private void btnMessageBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Which Callbacks does this MessageBox block?", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the running application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HipL.png)

This answers the question: My observation is, that the action in `Control.Invoke(Action)` is NOT blocked until after clicking away the MessageBox, at least not categorically.